# Microtype causes error in combination with system call LuaLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, luatex, tikz-external, microtype

I'm trying to plot some figures based on measurements with tikz because the number of data points is to large for LaTeX I'm using a 'system call' to use LuaLaTeX for them.

As long I do not load microtype everything works pretty well but for some reason microtype seems to cause an error. Any ideas?

> ```
> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. \end{axis}
> ```

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}% neue deutsche Rechtschreibung verwenden
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Wahl des Fonts, bzw.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Zeichkodierung , Umlaute \usepackage{}


%\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},
            final,
            tracking=true,
            kerning=true,
            spacing=true,
            factor=1200,
            stretch=50,
            shrink=0]{microtype}

      \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
      \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
      \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
      \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={},
            set decimal separator={,},
            clip marker paths=true,
            grid style={densely dotted, draw=black},
            x tick style={color=black},
            y tick style={color=black},
        }}
        \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
        \usetikzlibrary{patterns}      

        \newlength\figureheight
        \newlength\figurewidth

        \usetikzlibrary{external}
        \tikzexternalize[prefix=tikztmp/,figure name=tikztmp_sec\thesubsection_no,]
        \tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
        \tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\microtypesetup{kerning=false}
\microtypesetup{spacing=false}
\microtypesetup{expansion=false}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\microtypesetup{activate=false}
\microtypesetup{disable}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=10cm,
at={(0.790898in,0.967508in)},
scale only axis,
xlabel={$x~\rightarrow$},
ylabel={$y~\rightarrow$},
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=gray,line width=.45pt,mark size=.45pt,only marks,mark=*,mark options={solid}]
table [ x expr=\thisrow{tmess}*1e6, y=uoutmess, col sep=comma] {tmessuoutmess.csv};
\addlegendentry{Messung};

\addplot [color=black,solid,line width=1.5pt]
table [x expr=\thisrow{tapprox}*1e6, y=uoutapprox, col sep=comma] {tapproxuoutapprox.csv};
\addlegendentry{Approximation};

\addplot [color=black,loosely dotted,line width=1.5pt]
table [x expr=\thisrow{tsim}*1e6,y=uoutsim, col sep=comma] {tsimuoutsim.csv};
\addlegendentry{Simulation};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\microtypesetup{enable}
\microtypesetup{activate=true}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
\microtypesetup{expansion=true}
\microtypesetup{spacing=true}
\microtypesetup{kerning=true}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Values: [enter link description here](http://www72.zippyshare.com/v/QUAuSl3J/file.html)

Furthermore, I'm using:

```
MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15
LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062821
```

---

edit: Because LuaLateX does not support spacing and kerning I tried to disable this features for the tikzpicture environment but it seems not to work any ideas?

```
\microtypesetup{kerning=false}
\microtypesetup{spacing=false}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\microtypesetup{spacing=true}
\microtypesetup{kerning=true}
```

Comment: Does that mean that your example in the other thread actually works and wasn't the one you were working with?

Comment: The manual of microtype says that spacing and kerning only
work with pdfTeX. So they may not work with luaTeX. Try with
`kerning=false,spacing=false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the ifluatex-package and use it to deactivate settings not allowed or useful for lualatex:

```
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},
            final,
            tracking=true,
            %kerning=true,
            %spacing=true,
            factor=1200,
            stretch=50,
            shrink=0, 
            ]{microtype}
\ifluatex \else \microtypesetup{kerning=true,spacing=true}\fi
```

Answer (score 6):

The manual of microtype says that kerning and spacing
work only with pdfTeX. So try with

```
...,kerning=false,spacing=false,...
```

I have confirmed that

```
pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex
```

works.

Comment: It definitely works this way but I would prefer to disable kerning and spacing only in tikz -- i tried \microtypesetup{kerning=false), \microtypesetup{spacing=false) as well as \microtypesetup{disable) to disable this features for the tikzpicture but it seems not to work.